# Copy paste text and values if 2 cells match

Tags: google-sheets

I'm a perfumer and I've built a data base within Google Sheets, in which each ingredient's regulation is indicated. So for example:

| Ingredient | Regulation. |
| --- | --- |
| Coumarin | YES 1223/2009 |

& this for all possible ingredients.
When I create a new formula/recipe, I would like for the regulation to be immediately pasted next to the ingredient that I chose. If it's a number/value, I don't have any problems as I can use the SUMIF function. However when it's text, google sheets doesn't allow for the text to be pasted, only values. What function can I use to copy paste text from a data base, when 2 other cells match (th

Comment: "when 2 other cells match (th" Can you finish your thought? What second cell?

Comment: Please include a larger selection of your sample data and add an example of expected results. It sounds like you want to return a value from a cell based on a lookup of another value in the row or column beside it.  Try using one of FILTER, HLOOKUP, VLOOKUP, INDEX & MATCH, or QUERY depending on your data and preference.

Answer (score 0):

## Sample Data

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Ingredient** | **Regulation** |  | **Ingr. List** | **Reg. List** |
| **2** | Coumarin | YES 1223/2009 |  | Odepueur | OYE 1112/2365 |
| **3** |  |  |  | Pitvaper | NAY 1123/5673 |
| **4** |  |  |  | Coumarin | YES 1223/2009 |

## Formula in Cell `B2`

Any of the following formulas can be used in `B2` to return the appropriate regulation for the lookup value `Coumarin` from cell `A2`:

#### FILTER

```
=FILTER(E:E, D:D=A2)
```

#### VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, D:E, 2, 0)
```

#### INDEX & MATCH

```
=INDEX(E:E, MATCH(A2, D:D, 0))
```

#### QUERY

```
=QUERY(D:E, "Select E Where D = '"&A2&"'", 0)
```